# Scrolling Background with Cocos2D and Box2D

Tags: cocos2d-iphone, scroll, box2d

I am trying to create a simple game that mainly consists of a ball rolling down an incline.  The player's only control is to cause the ball to jump.  My question is, what is the best way to make it appear to roll while generally keeping the ball at the same place on the screen? I have considered CCCamera, but it seems like it's not the best option since I want a repeating background image.  Scrolling the background manually is also giving me trouble because it's not clear how to get the ball to stay in one place while letting Box2D handle the physics.  I'd appreciate any help as I've been stuck on this for quite a while.

Answer (score 1):

Use [CCFollow](http://www.learn-cocos2d.com/api-ref/KoboldTouch/latest/cocos2d-iphone/html/interface_c_c_follow.html) on the layer where you draw the game stuff, and let it follow the ball sprite:

```
[gameLayer runAction:[CCFollow actionWithTarget:ball]];
```